# Scraping and saving html files without images in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am scraping a website and after fetching each page, I'm storing the page in an html file. When I store the content in an html file, it stores the images as well and it's eating up all of my storage. Is there anyway that I can store the files without the images?

Here is the code:

```
for url in xrange(all_urls):
    driver.get(url)   
    page = driver.page_source
    f = open(url.replace('/','_') +'.html'  , 'w')
    f.write(page.encode('utf-8'))
    f.close()
    time.sleep(uniform(2, 5))
```

Comment: Are you trying to mirror the entire website ?  Can you post some code ?

Comment: I'm not mirroring the whole site, however, I have very limited storage. Right now, each file is around 600K.

Comment: Check the extension of `url` . Use a whitelist ( html, php, asp, etc ) to check if you want to save the content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL and save file with html format.

Comment: When I'm using curl, the website detects that I'm scraping. So I need to use webdriver and store the files.